# Rails 3 - How To Pass Object ID With Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 3 ruby 1.9

I am trying to pass a "products" id to a "Details" page and get error "Couldn't find Product without an ID"

This is the link in my browser address bar:

```
 http://localhost:3000/performance_details?product_id=8
```

My Controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
 def performance_details
  @title = "Performance Details"
  @products = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

The view that's passing the object ID

```
 <%=link_to 'Details', details_path(product_id: product) %>
```

The view receiving the object ID

```
 <%@products.each do |product| %>
 Do some stuff with products.....%>
 <%end%>
```

Routes File

```
 match 'details' => "products#details"
```

Comment: Are you having  `<%=link_to 'Details', details_path(product_id: product) %>` inside the loop?

Comment: @pavan yes it is inside the loop

Comment: That view page belongs to `details` or `products`?

Comment: Does any of the given answers worked out for you?

Comment: @Pavan the suggestion to change the controller to @product = Product.find(params[:product_id]) seems to have solved the routing issue but not im getting an error  "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Try changing back to `@products = Product.find(params[:id])` and in the link give like this `<%=link_to 'Details', details_path(product_id: product.id) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `@product` line in your products controller to the following:

```
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
```

From your comment below, you're only finding one product (note the change from plural `@products` to singular `@product`, so you don't want to use `each`. Change this:

```
<%@products.each do |product| %>
  Do some stuff with products.....%>
<%end%>
```

To just do things with `@product`, rather than `product`. So get rid of the outer block, and only use `@product`. I'd overall recommend the refactoring given in [Robin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23157175/2856441).

Comment: @Robin this seems to have resolved the routing issue however now im getting the error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: `@products = Product.find(params[:id])` only gets you one product, the one with the given id. You can't call each on that. And that's why he called it `@product` and not `@products`. Imo you should do what I suggested in my answer. You version is not railsy ;)

Comment: I agree with @Robin. As I said in my updated answer, you should go with his solution.

Comment: @Robin updated as you said i now get this "undefined method `each' for #<Product:0x43de350"

Answer (score 3):

Your parameter name is `product_id`, not just `id`. Here is how your controller should look like:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
 def performance_details
  @title = "Performance Details"
  @products = Product.find(params[:product_id])
end
```

Comment: this seems to have resolved the routing issue however now im getting the error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" any suggestions on how to fix that

Comment: Totally different issue, you should submit another question. Product with that id is not found or something else.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably how you should do it:

```
# routes
resources :products do
  member do
    get :performance_details
  end
end
```

-

```
# view
# your url will be /products/:id/performance_details
<%=link_to 'Details', performance_details_product_path(product) %>
```

-

```
# controller
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def performance_details
    @title = "Performance Details"
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have `id` in your params. According to your URL `/performance_details?product_id=8`, your id is in a variable called `product_id`.